# pip install --pre SQLAlchemy won't install version 1.4.0b1

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install beta version of SQLAlchemy in my virtual_env environment, but for some reason it checks a 1.3.20 version as a "prerelease" one, am I missing something here?

```
pip install --pre SQLAlchemy
```

returns me this

```
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy in ./datatest/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.20)
```

Comment: `pip install --pre --upgrade SQLAlchemy`